# AWS REST API Design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am looking into using AWS Cloudfront to develop an API that third parties can use to access data stored in an S3 bucket.

I have looked around alot and can not find any good examples if this is possible in the way I want to achieve it.

Basically what I need to be able to do is to provide access to JSON data in the S3 bucket using HTTP requests using signed URL's
that are signed using access keys that are generated for each user in Amazon's Identity and Access Management Console. I then
assign user specific policy's to each user to define what buckets, folders and object they can access.

Is it possible for third parties to access the data in this way without using the cloudfront API's to create signed url's or be AWS account holders?

Can I just provide them with the url to the object and their specific access key that I generated so the request will be something like this which they can access through a browser:

```
    https://www.example.com/examplebucket/examplefolder/exampleobject?key-pair-id=1111-1111-1111-1111
```

I have tried this myself but only get an access denied error - signature required, but the only way I can see to get this signature is
using the cloudfront api to create the signed url's.

Anyone have any ideas if this approach is possible or a better approach to take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative to Cloudfront private content would be to set up your own server. This would be fine for other AWS services like database. But since the resource is an S3 object it would be difficult to mask the url unless you are the one serving the request. So unfortunately Cloudfront is still the feasible way for access restriction. Please be noted you would still need to set a server to verify users who would get the signed url.

Comment: Thanks Inmyth for your answer. Setting the objects to public works great but I need to restrict access to different users, thats why I was wondering if I could assign users and access rights that would allow users without using Amazon api's to access the data.

Comment: I amended my answer and I apologized. At first I interpreted your question as providing public access without IAM. But from your comment and the original question, Cloudfront api remains the most feasible way in such scenario.

Comment: Thanks inmyth, I have a better idea now for my solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build a REST API use, API Gateway. This is the service completely designed for APIs and will address concerns like versioning, caching & etc. It internally uses Cloudfront so you will gets similar benefits there.